How do you run a Lua function from the Neovim command line?
Let's say I'm looking at:
:help tohtml():
tohtml.tohtml({winid}, {opt})                         *tohtml.tohtml.tohtml()*
    Converts the buffer shown in the window {winid} to HTML and returns the
    output as a list of string.

    Parameters: ~
      • {winid}  (`integer?`) Window to convert (defaults to current window)
      • {opt}    (`table?`) Optional parameters.
                 • {title}? (`string|false`, default: buffer name) Title tag
                   to set in the generated HTML code.
                 • {number_lines}? (`boolean`, default: `false`) Show line
                   numbers.
                 • {font}? (`string[]|string`, default: `guifont`) Fonts to
                   use.
                 • {width}? (`integer`, default: 'textwidth' if non-zero or
                   window width otherwise) Width used for items which are
                   either right aligned or repeat a character infinitely.

    Return: ~
        (`string[]`)

I see the function tohtml.tohtml(). It's exactly what I want and it's got all the parameters that I like.
I open Neovim and I'm in normal mode, how do I run this function?

You can call it like:
:lua require('tohtml').tohtml()

But you'll not see the result of the call.
To see the result of the call you could do:
:lua doc = require('tohtml').tohtml()
:lua for i, l in pairs(doc) do print(l) end

As a bonus, if you want to replicate the functionality of :TOhtml by writing to a file, you can do this
:lua doc = require('tohtml').tohtml(); file = io.open('test.html', 'w'); for i, l in pairs(doc) do file:write(l .. '\n') end; file:close()


:lua =require"tohtml".tohtml()

Note that = may not work in some very old nvim versions.
In this case, :lua print(vim.inspect(...)) should work instead.
Also,
:echo v:lua.require("tohtml").tohtml()

But the result will be formatted as VimL list rather than Lua table (not much difference for this particular example though).
